# SSH.NET compile Errors through jenkins

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, nuget, windows-server-2012-r2, ssh.net

I have some issues when try to compile the project using Jenkins. Locally it works fine using SSH.NET, but when I put my code to the windows server 2012R2 and using Jenkins build there. It shows me an error:

```
"SSH.NET" has already has a dependency defined for "SshNet.Security.Cryptography".
```

and build fail. Anyone knows what happened in the server side? Why it works locally but has compile errors in the server side?

Thanks

Comment: Do you put your code on a source control or in Visual Studio? And how do you configure your Build configurations in Jenkins build?

Comment: What's the nuget version on your Jenkins server? Can you run "nuget update -self" to update to the latest version and then try again?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your Jenkins installed SSH related plugins. Following screenshot shows the SSH related plugins installed in my Jenkins.
[image]

Then please check your Jenkins Configurations whether you configure any SSH related build configurations. In my successful build, I don't choose any SSH related options in build configurations. Please check your Build Configurations based on following screenshot. My project also installed SSH.NET package and it clone from GitHub. Except the project Url and Repositories Url, other options are in the default value.
[image]